# Error while downloading JAR file from repo

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to download a JAR file from a repo, but I'm getting the below error:

```
pget { 'Download 123 jar file':
  source         => 'url'       
  target         => 'C:\download,
  targetfilename => '123.jar',
  require        => File['E:\download'],
}
```

I'm getting the below error while executing the resource

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'pget'

Can anyone explain why I cannot use `pget`? Is there any other way to download the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either forgot to install the module that provides the `pget` type, or it was not installed correctly: https://forge.puppet.com/cyberious/pget

Install it either locally (using `puppet apply`) or on the master (using `puppet agent`) with:

```
puppet module install cyberious-pget
```

and then your resource will work.